# Can any lambda expression be expressed as a (templated) struct

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, functor

I am looking for a counterexample to disprove the claim that any lambda expression can be expressed as a (templated) struct. In other words, it is possible to write a source-to-source compiler that should be able lift every lambda expression out of any scope and express it as a templated functor class.

For example, as far as the end user is concerned, the following two are equivalent:

```
auto foo(int parm){
  ...
  auto f = [x,&y](int z) {..};
  ..
  return foo(parm);
}
```

can be expressed as

```
template<class X, class Y>
struct Closure {
  X x; Y y;
  auto operator()(int z) {..};  
};
auto foo(int parm) {
  ...
  auto f = Closure<decltype(x), decltype(y)&>{x,y};
  ...
  return f(parm);
}
```

Can this transformation always be done? If not, is there an example that can demonstrate this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. In fact, that's essentially how closure types are defined.

Comment: If it wasn't for polymorphic lambdas, you could even put the "manual lambda" at block scope.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How do you of that?

Comment: [Like so](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9532c213bf9231bf), but that not possible if `operator()` needs to be a template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closure type of a lambda is a class type with an overloaded `operator()` ([[expr.prim.lambda]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#3)). The transformation you describe *is* done every time a lambda expression is being dealt with - by the implementation.

Comment: For capture-less lambdas, you would also need a static function with the lambda's body so you can provide the conversion to a free function pointer, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The struct and the closure for the lambda aren't quite equivalent, since the captured variables aren't required to be in the struct itself. This part is implementation defined.

Comment: I suppose you want to say that  lambda implementations among different compilers are not necessarily equivalent. This just tells that implementing lambda as a templated struct is on an equal footing to any other implementation, as far as it is ISO C++ compliant. The question is then, is there anything that prevents lambda implementation as a templated struct to be ISO C++ compliant?